# Batch: nested for variable cannot be compared

Tags: batch-file

I need to compare two text files and get the lines that appear in both of them.
This is my code:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%1.txt) do (
    for /F "tokens=*" %%B in (%2.txt) do (
        echo %%A %%B
        if %%A==%%B echo OK                 
    )
)
```

I test files a.txt (lines a, c and d) and b.txt (lines a, b and c).
Output:

```
a a 
a b 
a c 
c a 
c b 
c c 
d a 
d b 
d c
```

If I substitute %%A==%%B with %%A==a, the output is the following:

```
a a 
OK                  
a b 
OK                  
a c 
OK                  
c a 
c b 
c c 
d a 
d b 
d c
```

While I test %%B==a instead, the output is the same like at %%A==%%B.

It seems to me like %%B couldn't be compared to anything. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, but your second file (b.txt) has trailing spaces.